# Execute specific bash script on Gentoo Linux startup

Tags: gentoo, daemon, startup-scripts

I own a VDS running Gentoo Linux and I am curious about how to execute specific bash script at startup of my VDS.

I just want to startup apache2 at boot time and run two thin instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your service already has an [init script](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4), you can add it to the `default` runlevel by running:

```
# rc-update add apache2 default
```

If not, depends on which [services system](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/openrc-migration.xml) you're using, add your scripts to the `/etc/conf.d/local.start` or `/etc/local.d/baselayout1.start`, something like this:

```
cd /path/to/your/app && thin start
```

Comment: I would like to call a shell script on startup, that contains some xmodmap directive for meyboard layout... Should I put it in /etc/local.d/myscript.start...?

Comment: http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Use_Multimedia_Keys

Comment: +1 but this is quite outdated though...

Answer (score 2):

To add apache2 at boot time:

```
$ rc-update add apache2 default
```

To start the script manually

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Also a really useful command is `rc-update -v show` which will show all the available init scripts and list at which runlevels they will execute.